# How to save Resource ID in click Event android

Tags: java, android

I have a custom bar (sortBar) with buttons. On click this function is called:

```java
public void setFoodItemSortType(View view)
{
        View oldView = view.findViewById(this.currentSortTitleID);
        if(oldView != null)
        {
            oldView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

        this.currentSortTitleID = view.getId();
        View newView = view.findViewById(this.currentSortTitleID);
        newView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

        this.LoadData();
    }
```

oldView is always null. Are ids changing in on click cycle? What i am doing wrong?

function is invoked via the onclick attribute:

```
 android:onClick="setFoodItemSortType"
```

Comment: please post out code from where you are invoking this method.

Comment: the function is invoked from the onclick attribute

Comment: Is `this` actually a subview of `view`? If not, you'll always get null.

Comment: android:onClick="setFoodItemSortType"

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe
why then newView is not null?

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe
this is the Activity in that case

Comment: You are not getting null for `newView` because you are setting the `this.currentSortTitleID` right above it to the id of the view that is coming into this method. Your mistake is that `this.currentSortTitleID` is not a valid view id at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it this way :

```
 View oldView;
public void setFoodItemSortType(View view)
{

    if(oldView != null)
    {
       oldView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    oldView = view 
    this.LoadData();
}
```